# C# - SerialPort Receive Doesn't Get All the Data at Once

Tags: c#

I have weird dilemma when it comes to Serial Port. I am sending a bunch of commands to device that has a microcontroller and getting responses back. Pretty typical stuff. Anyways, I am running into an issue where when I send a command, the DataReceived Event Handler does respond, but the problem is that I don't get all of the data back from it. As a result, the DataReceived Event Handler ends up getting called 4 times.

So instead of getting something like this:

```
0 - 2:16:38 PM: 126 23 100 69 0 0 99 3 225 2 203 2 174 2 179 2 125 93 3 15 3 
0 0 0 15 255 0 214 12 105 15 33 15 33 15 13 15 54 15 39 5 68 4 197 5 199 5 57 
5 0 0 0 134 225 
1 - 2:16:38 PM: 126 23 100 69 0 0 99 3 226 2 203 2 174 2 179 2 125 93 3 16 3 
0 0 0 15 255 0 224 12 105 15 23 15 33 15 2 15 74 15 39 5 58 4 197 5 198 5 57 
5 0 0 0 65 163 
2 - 2:16:38 PM: 126 23 100 69 0 0 99 3 226 2 202 2 174 2 178 2 125 93 3 15 3 
0 0 0 15 255 0 214 12 95 15 23 15 33 15 23 15 105 15 39 5 58 4 197 5 198 5 57 
5 0 0 0 63 128
```

The code ends up like this (not exact but giving an example):

```
0 - 2:16:38 PM: 126 23 100 69 0 0 99 3 225 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 - 2:16:38 PM: 2 203 2 174 2 179 2 125 93 3 15 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0              
0 - 2:16:38 PM: 15 255 0 214 12 105 15 33 15 33 15 13 15 54 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 - 2:16:38 PM: 15 39 5 68 4 197 5 199 5 57 5 0 0 0 134 225 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Where the first data line takes 4 event calls instead of 1. I am assuming that the microcontroller is still sending out data since I am sending all of my write data all at once. But I am hoping there is a way of controlling it so I don't get all those event calls (as I prefer getting the byte array in one single array instead of chunks).

This is all being programmed by Visual Studio 2010, but I can get my hands on 2013 if need be. Here is the sample code I used to get results similar to above (I am aware about the file streamwriter doesn't close when working with this, but I am just using the main code as an example):

```
namespace SerialCommunicationsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static UInt64 count = 0;
        static SerialPort port;
        static System.IO.StreamWriter file;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\li\Desktop\Serial.txt");
            port = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            port.Open();

            port.ReadTimeout = 400;
            port.WriteTimeout = 400;
            byte[] output = { 0x7E, 0x64, 0x17, 0x01, 0x45, 0x40, 0xFA, 0x7E };
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPortDataReceived);
            /* Loop, send message, and have event handler handler handle incoming event */
            while (count < UInt64.MaxValue)
            {
                port.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
            }

            return;
        }
        static void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] test = new byte[256];

            try
            {
                string data2 = "";
                port.Read(test, 0, 256);
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
                {
                    data2 += test[i] + " ";
                }
                string writeOut = count + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ": " + data2;
                Console.WriteLine(writeOut);
                file.WriteLine(writeOut);
                count++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior or `Read` the function returns a `int` for a reason.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the entire response back without the multiple DataReceived Event Calls Edit: or am I going to have to rig some kind of termination sequence?

Comment: You have to reassemble message fragments yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is your responsabilty to assemble mutiple read calls in to a single "message" if you know the fixed message length you can repeatedly call `Read` till you have read all the bytes to fill a `byte[]` then you pass that array off to the other functions.

```
    const int MessageSize = 256;
    byte[] test = new byte[MessageSize];
    int offset = 0;


    static void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        try
        {
            offset += port.Read(test, offset, MessageSize - offset);

            if(offset == MessageSize)
            {
                string data2 = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
                {
                    data2 += test[i] + " ";
                }
                string writeOut = count + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ": " + data2;
                Console.WriteLine(writeOut);
                file.WriteLine(writeOut);
                count++;
                offset = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How about in the case of a non-fixed message size response? The message is bookended by two bytes of 0x7e, So I have to assume that I can get the code to see that second 0x7e then stop the transmitting?

Comment: Yep, the system is called "Message Framing", [usually you will see tutorials on it for TCP/IP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) but serial has the exact same constraints and following a TCP/IP tutoral will get you the info you need.

Comment: Don't do this, you will have multiple `DataReceived` handlers running simultaneously fighting for the fragments and a race condition on adding them to the buffer.  Total disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<byte> dataBuffer = new List<byte>();
byte[] tempBuff;
var bytesReaded = pt.Read(inBuff, 0, inBuffSize);
while (bytesReaded > 0)
{
    tempBuff = new byte[bytesReaded];
    Array.Copy(inBuff, tempBuff, bytesReaded);
    dataBuffer.AddRange(tempBuff);
    bytesReaded = pt.Read(inBuff, 0, inBuffSize);
}
```